# How to handle authentication window in chrome with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests, ui-testing

Hi Im having trouble entering my details the authentication pop up when i enter my stage URL im testing, is there a way to click on certain coordinates on a page with selenium and java, or even tools that help with this? (i tried the pw and username in the url aswell but it doesnt work). Obviously there are no elements or xpath available for this page

Heres a pic of the window:

[image]

Comment: Where is the focus when this box pops up? You could experiment with send keys, including tab and enter along with the characters themselves.

Comment: @maio, this may be a duplicate, but I don't think that's it. I believe this is a pop-up that is not embedded inside the main page.

Comment: Its not a  duplicate Ive already stated ive tried that

Comment: @MattCremeens Ive tried using the tab keys as that usually solves the issue but it seems to be designed to not allow these to work, other than actually clicking in the input boxes

Comment: Does the pop-up have a title? You can switch to a window with a particular title using selenium.

Comment: I cant even right click to get information on the box, im trying to find a way to click on the actual input box to enter the information

Comment: I realize that, but the title bar would have a title in it that you can read, perhaps.

Comment: It just says the URL of the page

Comment: What is the URL and how did you get the pop-up to display?

Comment: Perhaps that is the title. You could try: `driver.switchTo().window("the url listed in the title bar");` And then use send keys from there.

Comment: Its the url of the stage environment im testing in my company, they place this  authentication so it couldnt be accessed by anyone outside the company, but in order to test the features i need to get passed it

Comment: Ill give that a try

Comment: Just a [suggestion](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/handle-authentication-popup-window/).